# Deserialize CSV with CustomHeaders using ServiceStack.Text

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm trying to use ServiceStack.Text for deserializing a csv file containing custom headers.

```
var csv = "Col-1,Col-2" + Environment.NewLine +
"Val1,Val2" + Environment.NewLine +
"Val3,Val3" + Environment.NewLine;

public class Line
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
}

ServiceStack.Text.CsvConfig<Line>.CustomHeadersMap = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"Col1", "Col-1"},
    {"Col2", "Col-2"}
};

var r2 = ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<Line>>(csv);

Assert.That(r2.Count() == 2, "It should be 2 rows");
Assert.That(r2[0].Col1 == "Val1", "Expected Val1");
Assert.That(r2[0].Col2 == "Val2", "Expected Val2");
```

CustomHeadersMap is working when SerializeToString is used. But I can't get it working when using DeserializeFromString.

Answer (score 0):

The sample text you're trying to deserialize has very little in common with the [Comma-Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (CSV) format that [ServiceStack's CSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/CSV-Format) should be used to deserialize.

I'm not aware of any .NET library that can deserialize the text format in your Sample so I'd recommend running it through some a custom regex/normalizer which can convert it to a proper **.csv** file and deserialize that instead. Here's an example in JavaScript:

```
var txt = `---------------
| Col-1 | Col-2 |
---------------
| Val1 | Val2 |
---------------
| Val3 | Val4 |
---------------
`;

var csv = txt
    .replace(/^-*/mg, '')
    .replace(/(^\| | \|$)/mg, '')
    .replace(/ \| /mg,',')
    .split(/\r?\n/g)
    .filter(s => s)
    .join('\r\n')
```

Where `csv` now contains the string:

```
Col-1,Col-2
Val1,Val2
Val3,Val4
```

Comment: The example had a wrong separator, it should be correct now. Is CustomHeadersMap used in the deserializer?

Comment: @Kai-Rune the sample text looks like exactly the same? i.e. nothing close to CSV, I've updated my answer with an example. I've also just [added a commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/6085b45e63520f788d1d0b0b748cd2541e37e652) which applies these custom headers to the CSV deserializer as well. This change is now available from v4.0.57 on MyGet but you'll need to [clear your MyGet cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet#redownloading-myget-packages) to fetch the latest package versions.

Comment: I still get an error with the updated nuget package, please run the code in the question. The csv data is included in the code.

Comment: I'm also looking for this. The code example from Kai-Rune doesn't work in ServiceStack.Text 4.5.14 (installed from Nuget) @mythz