# Deserialize CSV with CustomHeaders using ServiceStack.Text: not working?

Tags: c#, csv, deserialization, servicestack, servicestack-text

consider following class:

```
class Foo {
    public string bar { get; set; }
    public string rab { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[Foo bar={0}, rab={1}]", bar, rab);
    }
}
```

And following code:

```
var csv1 =
    "bar,rab" + Environment.NewLine +
    "a,b" + Environment.NewLine +
    "c,d" + Environment.NewLine +
    "e,f" + Environment.NewLine;

var csv2 =
    "xbar,xrab" + Environment.NewLine +
    "a,b" + Environment.NewLine +
    "c,d" + Environment.NewLine +
    "e,f" + Environment.NewLine;

Console.WriteLine(CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<Foo>>(csv1).First());

CsvConfig<TMDBEntity>.CustomHeadersMap = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"bar", "xbar"},
    {"rab", "xrab"}
};

Console.WriteLine(CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<Foo>>(csv2).First());
```

It is printing:

```
[Foo bar=a, rab=b]
[Foo bar=, rab=]
```

while I would expect it to print

```
[Foo bar=a, rab=b]
[Foo bar=a, rab=b]
```

Why is it not picking up the custom headers using xbar and xrab?

ServiceStack.Text version is 4.5.14.0

Comment: There is a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851708/deserialize-csv-with-customheaders-using-servicestack-text. The statci CsvConfig object writes the dictionary in the CsvWriter<T> and CsvReader<T>, try "CcvConfig<Foo>.CustomHeadersMap = ...." for your example. If wont use theheaders ofthe TMDBEntity

Answer (score 2):

This issue should be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/f266f9bfa93f1da05d8b33b422dc837ac52d4886) which is available from ServiceStack v5.0.0 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Note you need to configure `CsvConfig<Foo>` in order to change how `Foo` is deserialized, e.g:

```
CsvConfig<Foo>.CustomHeadersMap = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"bar", "xbar"},
    {"rab", "xrab"}
};
```